# jQuery class count on a certain table column number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been at this for a while and want to know the best way of achieving my goal if anyone has any ideas!

Example:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Hello</td>
<td>Hello (I want to check this column)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hello 2</td>
<td class="active">Hello 2 (this column)</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery I've got so far (I'm traversing from a clicked element):

```
var length = $(self).closest("tbody").find("tr").find("td.active").length;
```

Obviously this gets all the active classes of td, when I only want the second column. I've tried:

```
var length = $(self).closest("tbody").find("tr").find("td:eq(1).active").length;
```

This does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: eq is 0 based so maybe try eq(0)

Comment: eq(0) would mean the first <td> though, so eq(1) would be the second, which is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: But you say *...when I only want the first column*. Besides, what is "self" ?

Comment: Sorry, I'll change my question to only wanting the second column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to get the table cells in the **second** column (not the first as indicated in the question) which have the class `active` on them. If that's the case, you can use the following:

```
var length = $(self).closest('tbody').find('tr').find('td:eq(1)').filter('.active').length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mikemccaughan/g6mnn/

Comment: Aha, filter seemed to be what I was looking for, works a charm - thank you!

Comment: Your answer does not work and does not match your fiddle which DOES work.

Answer (score 1):

I think your selector isn't doing what you expect it to.  I would have expected what you're expecting, but check out this paragraph from the `eq()` documentation (emphasis mine):

> Note that since JavaScript arrays use 0-based indexing, these
>   selectors reflect that fact. This is why **$('.myclass:eq(1)') selects
>   the second element in the document with the class myclass**, rather than
>   the first. In contrast, :nth-child(n) uses 1-based indexing to conform
>   to the CSS specification.

So you're going to want to use `td:eq(1)` *without* the class selector, then filter your results, and *then* count them:

```
var length = $(self).closest("tbody").find("td:eq(1)").filter(".active").length;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Correct answer, but you got there second unfortunately :( Thank you!

Comment: @thedixon - No worries; just happens sometimes.  Cheers!